# Can you set default Schema for SQL 2008 Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a schema called application.  Is there a way that, rather than using the syntax

```
SELECT * FROM application.table
```

I can set the default schema so that I can just use

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

It would be the same idea as a using statement I suppose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default schema for all sql server users is "dbo", You can alter the default schema for a user by using commands ALTER USER

```
ALTER USER UserName WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = application;
```

Answer (score 3):

It will be great to have a *use* statement for schemas.
You can vote the [feature suggestion on Microsoft connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=390528).